# my footer is on the side of the page and its acting like a container instead of a footer

Tags: html, css

[image: here's an image of what I've working on and what is happening on the page]

What I want to is to make it naturally at the bottom because on the video I watched he does not even need to set the position of the footer, on his page the footer naturally goes to the bottom of the page but mine does not it goes on the side of the page.

I already tried to set its position to absolute and manually position it with ems now the problem is it's not centered like there'[enter image description here][2]s a huge margin on the left of the page

here's the code:

```css
footer{
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #143774;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -65em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="whole-container whole">
      <div class="nav-container titles">
        <a href="#" class="main-title">
          <h1 class="title">Living the social life
          </h1>
          <p class="subtitle">A BLOG EXPLORING MINIMALISM IN LIFE
          </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-container navs">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="home.html" class="current-page" style="text-decoration: none;">Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="about.html" class="nav-links">About
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="projects.html" class="nav-links">Projects
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <main>
      <article class="featured-article">
        <img
             class="main-article-img"
             src="hand-wash-warm-water.jpg"
             alt="failed to load img"
             />
        <h2 class="article-title" >Lorem ipsum
        </h2>
        <p class="article-info" >9/21/2022
        </p>
        <p class="main-text" >
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
          ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
          <a class="direct"href="#">
            Duis aute irure dolor in
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
            pariatur.
          </a> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="direct" >CONTINUE READING
        </a>
      </article>
      <article class="sub-article">
        <div class="main-text">
          <h2  class="sub-article-title">Lorem ipsum dolor
          </h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
            enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
            nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </p>
          <a  class= "direct" href="#">CONTINUE READING
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="image-info">
          <img
               class="sub-article-img"
               src="Practice-pic1.jpg"
               alt="failed to load img"
               />
          <p class="article-info">9/21/2022
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="sub-article">
        <div class="main-text">
          <h2  class="sub-article-title">Lorem ipsum dolor
          </h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
            enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
            nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </p>
          <a  class= "direct" href="#">CONTINUE READING
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="image-info">
          <img
               class="sub-article-img"
               src="Practice-pic1.jpg"
               alt="failed to load img"
               />
          <p class="article-info">9/21/2022
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="sub-article" >
        <div class="main-text">
          <h2  class="sub-article-title">Lorem ipsum dolor
          </h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
            enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
            nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </p>
          <a  class= "direct" href="#">CONTINUE READING
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="image-info">
          <img
               class="sub-article-img"
               src="Practice-pic1.jpg"
               alt="failed to load img"
               />
          <p class="article-info">9/21/2022
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </main>
    <aside class="sidebar">
      <div class="widget main-widget">
        <h2 class="widget-maintitle">ABOUT ME
        </h2>
        <img  class="widget-img" src="292537123_1421294871643833_8034488637593337509_n.jpg" alt="failed to load img">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        <div class="recent-post">
          <h2 class="widget-maintitle">RECENT POSTS
          </h2>
          <img
               class="widget-img"
               src="itchy-eye-guy-330x220.jpg"
               alt="failed to load img"
               />
          <h3 class="widget-subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor set amet
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="recent-post">
          <img
               class="widget-img"
               src="itchy-eye-guy-330x220.jpg"
               alt="failed to load img"
               />
          <h3 class="widget-subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor set amet
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="recent-post">
          <img
               class="widget-img"
               src="itchy-eye-guy-330x220.jpg"
               alt="failed to load img"
               />
          <h3 class="widget-subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor set amet
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <footer>
      <p>Living The Simple Life
      </p>
      <p>Copyright 2019
      </p>
    </footer>
    </body>
```

Comment: Your `<footer>` is inside `<div class="container">`. Additionally, you haven't closed off that div

Comment: I'd suggest using something to auto-format/indent your HTML. It can save on a lot of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your footer is inside a div that contains a css style with a left margin or left padding. Also I suggest that you should also include a snippet of your html code because the problem might also be there like in this case.